# Unusual terminology of vector used

Tags: nomenclature, cloning, vector

What is the significance of a+ in the name pET-28 a(+)? Is there any a- strain and differences between a,a+,a-?

Comment: This is not a bacterial strain. pET is a [plasmid system](https://www.addgene.org/vector-database/2565/) generally used for protein overexpression. If your stocks are labelled like this then you should ask the person who created them.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 versions (a,b, and c) of this **plasmid** with different multiple cloning sites.

You can safely ignore the "(+)" part unless you are packing your plasmids into viruses.

You can learn about the details and see sequences from the resources available on [the Millipore website](http://www.emdmillipore.com/US/en/product/pET-28a+-DNA-Novagen,EMD_BIO-69864#documentation).  I found this by searching for "pET-28 a(+)" ...